# Autoloading and PSR-0/PSR-4

Tags: php, composer-php

I, like many others it seems, am having trouble getting my head around when and how to use auto-loading. I think I understand the concept of composer and PSR-0/PSR-4 and directory structure that this requires. But if I'm building my own project using my own MVC framework

- Should I now put all my class files in a src folder inside the vendor folder
- Do I then edit the composer autoload file?
- Or do I still keep the original structure and just use my own autoloader?

  ```
  -project
      -app
          -core /Main.php
          -controllers /Controller.php
          -models /User.php
      /index.php
  ```

Since composer comes with its own autoloader which will load all dependenies that I may want to include with my project and if I'm not going to make my website into a distributed project do I even need my own namespacing? Why don't I just stick with includes/requires?

And finally, if I do adopt namespacing using a closure like this

```
 function __autoload($class){
    require $class .'.php';
 });
```

do I need to require the autoload.php file in all pages where I load my classes as I do with the old include/require of the past. Is the above file correct? I think the namespace would be

```
<?php
namespace app\core;  //for Main.php
namespace app\controllers; //for Controller.php

use app\controllers\Controller; //if I call the class
```

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning of your main file (maybe `/var/www/dist/index.php`) you just include the Composer or whatever autoloader you use.

```
<?php
if ( file_exists( __DIR__.'/path/to/vendor/autoload.php' ) )
    require __DIR__.'/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then you can either add shortcuts to the classes that you use in a file by making use of the `use` statement

```
use MyNamespace\Controller\Index,
    MyNamespace\Service\FooService;

use Zend\Foo\Bar;
use Symfony\Baz\Biz;
use Etc\Etc\Etc;

// Refers to \Zend\Foo\Bar
$bar = new Bar;
```

or just use the full path when instantiating a class

```
$bar = new \Zend\Foo\Bar;
```

To add your own namespace, just add it to your `composer.json` file

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "MyNamespace\\" : "src/"
    }
}
```

and open your command line interface/terminal/console and add the namespace to the autoloader

```
# local install of Composer in your project
php composer.php dump-autoload
# or global install and `composer` is in your $PATH
composer dump-autoload
```

There is a rule:

> One class per file

And if your project really is ([PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) *deprecated* or) [PSR-4 compatible](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), then you don't use more than one `namespace` in one file. A class name gets (in the PSR-4 FIG standard) defined as

> A fully qualified class name has the following form:
>
> `\<NamespaceName>(\<SubNamespaceNames>)*\<ClassName>`
>
> The contiguous sub-namespace names after the "namespace prefix" [note: `\` is the "root") correspond to a subdirectory within a "base directory", in which the namespace separators represent directory separators.

with the following example:

```
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Fully Qualified Class Name   | Namespace Prefix | Base Directory         | Resulting File Path                   |
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| \Acme\Log\Writer\File_Writer | Acme\Log\Writer  | ./acme-log-writer/lib/ | ./acme-log-writer/lib/File_Writer.php |
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```